# Dronacharya fighting for Kauravas in Mahabharata?

Tags: mahabharata, dronacharya, explanation

[Dronacharya](https://www.google.com/amp/s/bharathgyanblog.wordpress.com/2018/08/28/dronacharya/amp/)

[Arjuna - Best Archer](https://www.google.com/amp/s/hindi.asianetnews.com/amp/religious-news/when-and-why-did-guru-dronacharya-give-arjuna-the-gift-of-being-the-best-archer--q0mv44)

[Why Dronacharya designed Chakrayuh?](https://www.google.com/search?q=dronacharya%20chakravyuh&oq=dr&aqs=chrome.0.69i59l2j69i60l3j46i39i175i199j69i57j46i199i433i465i512.1268j0j7&client=ms-android-samsung-ss&sourceid=chrome-mobile&ie=UTF-8)

[Dronacharya awards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dronacharya_Award)

[yudhishthir kunjarova](https://www.google.com/search?q=yudhishthir%20kunjarova&sxsrf=ALiCzsYKNswvb_Ax5JW5pql7yFXWyDCfOA%3A1656902008410&ei=eFHCYpnXGPWx4-EPqOae4AE&oq=yudhishthir%20kunjarova&gs_lcp=ChNtb2JpbGUtZ3dzLXdpei1zZXJwEAM6BwgAEEcQsAM6BAgeEApKBAhBGABQqgxYkRpgjSloAXABeACAAdcBiAHNCJIBBTAuNC4ymAEAoAEByAECwAEB&sclient=mobile-gws-wiz-serp)

[Dronacharya unable to capture Yudhisthira](https://www.google.com/search?q=yudhishthir%20kunjarova&sxsrf=ALiCzsZsjk8oXnX_n-NXkgMsOTv6t29X0A%3A1656903064057&source=hp&ei=mFXCYsw66pex4w_YrJyQAQ&oq=&gs_lcp=ChFtb2JpbGUtZ3dzLXdpei1ocBABGAAyBwgjEOoCECcyBwgjEOoCECcyBwgjEOoCECcyBwgjEOoCECcyBwgjEOoCECcyBwgjEOoCECcyBwgjEOoCECcyBwgjEOoCECcyBwgjEOoCECcyBwgjEOoCECcyBwgjEOoCECcyDQguEMcBEK8BEOoCECcyBwgjEOoCECcyBwguEOoCECcyBwgjEOoCECdQAFgAYJUNaABwAHgAgAGhA4gBoQOSAQM0LTGYAQCwAQ8&sclient=mobile-gws-wiz-hp#fpstate=ive&vld=cid:5d788765,vid:4IboQLXf1EI,st:0)

[The fall of Drona](https://www.lonelyphilosopher.com/the-fall-of-drona-aswathama-hatha-iti-narova-kunjarova/)

I would like to know why Dronacharya fought for Kauravas rather than for Pandavas in Mahabharata?

What are the different reasons?

Arjuna was a favourite student of Acharya Dronacharya. Isn' it?

Why Dronacharya designed the Chakrayuh?

If Arjuna was his favourite student, he designed the Chakrayuh for Killing Abhimanyu son of Arjuna?

Will you call Dronacharya a good teacher no doubt he was guru of Arjuna ?

Do you feel Dronacharya awards should be given named after Dronacharya?

How many years did Dronacharya lived?

[Bhishma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bhishma)

Should we rename Dronacharya award to Bhishma award?

Comment: Hello. Your question has become too broad after editing. I would kindly request you to please stick to your original question, as answered by me. And you may ask new questions, each separately, for the new parts you have added. Otherwise the question is too much broad, as of now. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dronacharya was duty bound to the kingdom of Hastinapura, that's why he had to fight from the Kauravas side.

He himself says so.

> #### [Chapter 43](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-mahabharata-mohan/d/doc375192.html#note-e-141765), Book 6, Mahabharata
>
> [द्रोण उवाच](https://sanskritdocuments.org/mirrors/mahabharata/mbhK/mahabharata-k-06-sa.html)।
>
> यदि मां नाभिगच्छेथा युद्धाय कृतनिश्चयः। शपेयं त्वां महाराज परीभावाय
> सर्वशः ॥ तद्युधिष्ठिर तुष्टोऽस्मि पूजितश्च त्वयाऽनघ। अनुजानामि
> युध्यस्व विजयं समवाप्नुहि ॥  करवाणि च ते कामं ब्रूहि त्वमभिकाङ्क्षितम्
> । एवं गते महाराज युद्धादन्यत्किमिच्छसि ॥
> **अर्थस्य पुरुषो दासो दासस्त्वर्थो न कस्यचित्। इति सत्यं महाराज बद्धोऽस्म्यर्थेन कौरवैःक ॥  ब्रवीम्येतत्क्लीबवत्त्वां
> युद्धादन्यत्किमिच्छसि। योत्स्येऽहं कौरवस्यार्थे तवाशास्यो जयो मया ॥**
>
> > "Drona said,
> >
> > 'If, having resolved to fight, you had not come to me (thus), I would
> > have cursed you. O king, for your complete overthrow. I am, however,
> > gratified, O Yudhishthira, and honoured by you, O sinless one. I
> > permit you, fight and obtain victory. I will also fulfil your wish.
> > Say what you have to say. Under these circumstances, battle excepted,
> > what dost you wish? **A man is the slave of wealth, but wealth is not
> > one’s slave. This is quite true, O king! Bound I have been with
> > (their) wealth by the Kauravas! It is for this that like a eunuch I
> > shall fight for the sake of the Kauravas.** It is for this that like a
> > eunuch I am uttering these words—Battle excepted, what dost you wish?
> > I shall fight for the sake of the Kauravas, but will pray for your
> > victory.'<sup>[**5**]</sup>

The Translator K.M. Ganguli notes -

> Footnote [5]:
>
> *The sense of the first line is that because I am bound by the Kauravas
> with their wealth, therefore, I am obliged to make this reservation in
> the matter of granting you your wishes. That reservation really
> nullifies my promise.*

Comment: one thing is that the same line 3 people said, dronacharya, kripacharya, bhisma

Comment: Yes. True. @YOuwillnotknow All three of them said the same thing.

Answer (score 4):

When Dronacharya was in distress, he was given shelter in Hastinapur by Bhishma. So he was obliged to follow and support Bhishma and Bhishma was in support of Kauravas because of his vow.

> O king, I do not say this to you from cowardice, nor for the sake of wealth. I am enjoying the wealth that Bhishma gave me, and not you, O best of kings. I do not desire, O king, to have from you my means of sustenance. **Where Bhishma is, there Drona must be.** Do what Bhishma has told you. O grinder of foes, give unto the sons of Pandu half the kingdom. O sire, I acted as their preceptor as much as thine. Indeed, even as Asvatthaman is to me, so is Arjuna of white steeds. What use is there of much declamation? Victory is there where righteousness is.'

> **Udyog Parva CXLVIII**